# how to use content-security-policy tag for silverlight web application over Entity framework

Tags: silverlight, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement security for our silverlight based website. One of the measures is to implement content-security-policy tag. How to do that? is it added to web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Typically CSP is set in the HTTP header, but it can be in a `<meta>` tag. You can set the header in your web.config in the

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:;"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

However, Silverlight is an object that runs in it's own context - it doesn't care about CSP and will completely ignore it. The only thing you'll be able to do with CSP is make sure that your Silverlight .xap files are only loaded from your server (with `object-src 'self';`).

If all your content is via Silverlight then you probably don't have to worry about traditional XSS attacks as it won't be able to execute Javascript based exploits. Silverlight is a deprecated and legacy technology though, so there are probably plenty of unpatched holes in it that a dedicated hacker could get in to.